# Django 404,500,403 custom page redirection problem

Tags: python, django, templates

I was unable to configure 400,500,404 etc page in my webapp. I have made one dedicated project to test these custom behave but failed to get any result. I have taken following steps to set up those custom pages :

1. Configured project folder urls.py with these lines:

   ```
   handler404 = 'testapp.views.not_found'
   handler500 = 'testapp.views.server_error'
   handler403 = 'testapp.views.permission_denied'
   handler400 = 'testapp.views.bad_request'
   ```
2. I have created one app name testapp and pasted below codes inside the views.py

   ```
   def server_error(request):
       return render(request, 'testapp/500.html')


   def not_found(request):
       return render(request, 'testapp/404.html')


   def permission_denied(request):
       return render(request, 'testapp/403.html')


   def bad_request(request):
       return render(request, 'testapp/400.html')
   ```
3. Created template directory inside testapp and again created testapp directory inside template directory.
4. Set `Debug = Flase`.
5. But when I hit any wrong url it says: `"A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator."`

Here's my directory structure:

[image]

Any Suggestions that I can do to bring the desired result ?

Comment: The question contains some typo's that might (not) be in the code. For example the indentation is of (the first `def` here has two spaces in front), furthermore `DEBUG` (with uppercases) should be `False` (not `Flase`).

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you don't turn off `DEBUG`, you'll probably get a more useful error message which will help you debug your problem.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#handler404) says you need to implement a specific method signature rather than just a standard view, as well as returning `HttpResponseNotFound`. This has been true since 1.9, so it's probably relevant to you here (I assume you're using at least 1.11).